# How can I compare an audio recording with a song in android?

Tags: android, comparison, pitch

I haven't tried voice recognition features in Android and I am not sure if I should go that way or should I start looking for pitch detection algorithm?

I am very confused, what I want to accomplish is a comparison between a song and a voice recording (which is the same song but sung by the user) I want to compare both recordings and give a score depending the similarity. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Fast Fourier Transformation algorithm for this.